# Find max value and the corresponding column/index name in entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I want to select the maximum value in a dataframe, and then find out the index and the column name of that value.
Is there a way to do it?

Say, in the example below, I want to first find the max value (`31`), and then return the index and column name of that value `(20, R20D)`

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'R05D':[1,2,3],'R10D':[7,4,3],'R20D':[31,2,4]},index=[20,25,30])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you call `a.max(axis=0)` you get a series of the max on each column:

```
R05D     3
R10D     7
R20D    31
dtype: int64
```

If you call `max` on that series you get it's maximum so:

```
a.max(axis=0).max()
#31
```

gives you the maximum value. Similarly:

```
a.max(axis=0).idxmax()
#R20D
```

gives you the column name and

```
a.max(axis=1).idxmax()
#20
```

will give you the row.

Comment: Thanks.  Please consider accepting my answer if it has helped you.

Comment: RyanWalker: always best to wait t least 24h for other answers, even if you completely answered it. @Boud's answer is interesting, although probably less scalable.

Answer (score 8):

Turn your dataframe into a MultipleIndex Series and ask for the index of the max element with `idxmax` function:

```
coord = a.stack().idxmax()
coord
(20, 'R20D')
```

To get the value, use the coordinates against `loc`:

```
df.loc[coord]
31
```

To get the numeric index you can use `a.stack().argmax()`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The `a.stack().argmax()` returned `2` (which is the index number) instead of `(20, 'R20D')` as you noted.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment with my limited reputation, here is an extra answer to @Boud 's answer: It didn't work for me with `argmax()`, but using `idxmax()` solved the problem and returns the correct output of `(20, "R20D")`

```
coord = a.stack().idxmax()
coord
(20, 'R20D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this goes beyond what the OP asked for, if you need to find the top n (e.g. 3) values, you can do:

```
a.stack().sort_values(ascending=False).head(3)
```

which gives you a new ordered df with the original (index, column) as the new MultiIndex:

```
20  R20D    31
    R10D     7
25  R10D     4
```

`tail(2)` will similarly give you the lowest 2 values.